# Google AR Core enabled Devices

Tags: firebase, augmented-reality, arcore, google-developers-console, android-augmented-reality

We have created one mobile app, that is Google AR Core based. So naturally users have to have AR Core enabled device. I have two questions mentioned below:

1. Is there any other option for users not having AR Core enabled device but have smart phone & can use this app with all it's full functionalities
2. How fast Google is getting this AR Core feature enabled in each & every available models of each brand.. this will help us to understand how successfull this app would be.. as we are targeting Indian Mass..so the range of smart phone models is very vast..

Kindly respond..

Thanks & Regards,
Avishek Roy

Answer (score 0):

1. Set minSDK version in gradle to 16 for ARCore optional apps.
2. Personally, Google is very slow with its ARCore deployment, so I am not that confident.

Answer (score 0):

1.Set minSDK version in gradle to 16 for ARCore optional apps.

2.Personally, Google is very slow with its ARCore deployment, so I am not that confident.

your welcome